# Приложение (.exe файл) без окон.

Tags: c++

Необходимо создать приложение (.exe файл) без окон. Кроме этого он не должен отображаться в Диспетчере задач в списке "Приложения". Должен висеть лишь в процессах.

Как это реализовать, что посоветуете?
P.S. Использую MVS 17, C++.

Comment: Ну и не создавайте окон в приложении. Никто же не заставляет это делать.

Comment: А почему так? А не вирус ли это? Я себе такое "приложение" что небудет в списке "Приложения" - не хочу. Может быть вам нужно не приложение, а служба? Тогда поищите инфу по запросу служба на с++. Есть [MSDN](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CppWindowsService-cacf4948) Служба накладывает дополнительные трудности и ограничения - читать чем служба отличается от приложения.

Comment: Нет, это не вирус. Это доп приложение к основному проекту (написанный на С#). Я новичок в этом, поэтому не могу просто так взять и "не создавать окна". Есть более подробные описания (статьи и т.п.)?

Comment: Что бы не создавать окна - создайте простой обычный оконный проэкт, удалите создание окон из мейна (ели оно там есть) и вызывайте `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep` время от времени (а то приложение будет считаться повисшим).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хотите самый простой вариант? :)

Делайте обычное консольное приложение. Потом берете утилиту `editbin` и применяете ее к своей exe'шке как

```
editbin /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS your.exe
```

Все. Запускайте и можете начинать искать :)

Только учтите - вывод на экран, как и ввод с клавиатуры - понятие для этой программы неприменимое...

Comment: Зачем такая перверсия с editbin? почему бы сразу не собирать с `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS`?

Comment: Можно и так. Только с проектами в среде заморачиваться нужно соответствующим образом. А из командной строки проще так - заодно и отладить проще...

Answer (score -1):

1. Создайте оконное приложение. На выходе получите готовую `exe`.
2. Найдите начальный файл с начальной процедурой WinMain. Так же можно трассировкой F11 (для студии) туда попасть. Удалите создание окон. Т.е.

`/*что то впереди*/ WinMain(/*параметры*/)`

`{`
<del>`Application.EnableVisualStyles()`</del>//Удалить весь майн

<del>`Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false)`</del>

<del>`Application.Run(new Form1())`</del> // самое главное Run удалить, именно он активирует окно.

`}`

На место удаленного кода - пишете свой код. Вместо создание окна - будет выполнен ваш код.

Можно удалить форму (из проэкта, в.т.ч файлы формы).

3. Не забывайте в длинных циклах делать  `Sleep(100)` иначе система будет считать что ваше приложение повисло.

Comment: Что-то вы в одну кучу насобирали WinMain() и явно шарповский код

Comment: Разные среды генерируют разный начальный код, не важно что там написано - всёравно нужно весь сгенерированый код удалить. Одни (borland, vs) генерируют код с использованием application, другие прямо в `WinMain` добавляют `CreateWindow`. Тем не менее пункт создать windows-app есть во многих средах. Что ж, судя по ответам можно предположить что editbin лучше запускать каждый раз после сборки, чем сразу нормальную сборку сделать. Удачи.

Comment: Вообще важно, что там написано. Т.к. вопрос о С++, ```WinMain``` и ```CreateWindow``` - пляска о WinAPI в стандартных библиотеках. Код с ```Application::Run``` - C++/CLI обертка на .NET Framework. И кстати в C++ используется gcnew для создания управляемого указателя, а доступ к членам осуществляется через ```::```. Что тут у вас - смесь WinMain с C# синтаксисом и его сгенерированным кодом по умолчанию